# useState delete array element in the state containing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state

my state orderDetail contain orderDetail json

I am getting the _id of the order which I want to delete in function eg _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea87,

now I want to remove this order from the orders array which is in orderdetail and update the state.

```
orderdetail = {
  _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea86,
  totalPrice: '400',
  orders: [
    {
      _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea87,
      quantity: '1',
      price: 200,
      name: 'Caramel Latte',
      category: 'Steaming Cups'
    },
    {
      _id: 60f1ab20891ced4818b5ea88,
      quantity: '1',
      price: 200,
      name: 'Cinnamon Latte',
      category: 'Steaming Cups'
    }
  ],
  confirm: 'done',
  timestamp: 1626450720332,
  name: 'xxx',
  email: 'xxx',
}
```

what I did is clone state then uses for loop to find an index of the order then remove that index element in clone then update state to clone. any other less computation method?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Also, that ID doesn't appear in your `orders` array

Comment: update the id sorry for that, I don't know how I solve it.

Comment: Are you using class-based or functional components?

Comment: functional components

Comment: what I did is clone state that uses for loop to find an index of the order then remove that index element to clone then update state to clone. any other less computation method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to so is set a new object with the `orders` array [*filtered*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as well as a new `totalPrice`.

For example

```js
const [orderDetail, setOrderDetail] = useState( /* whatever */ )

const deleteOrder = (id) => {
  setOrderDetail(prev => {
    // filter out the order by ID
    const orders = prev.orders.filter(({ _id }) => _id !== id)
   
    return {
      ...prev,
      orders, // overwrite orders
      totalPrice: orders.reduce((total, { quantity, price }) =>
          total + quantity * price, 0), // calculate new total
      timestamp: Date.now() // perhaps you want to update this too
    }
  })
}
```

This uses the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) version of the `useState()` hook to easily get access to the previous state value.

Comment: orders.reduce((total, { price }) => total + price, 0)
what this line do?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include quantity. I initially missed it because it's a string for some reason. You should really clean up your data types

Comment: @AlexAdvent it calculates the `totalPrice` by reducing the new `orders` array to a number by summing the (price * quantity)